# Scaling a Server Horizontally

Tags: mysql, web-services, scalability, scaling, horizontal-scaling

I have a question about scalability. Let's say I have a multiplayer game, such as Uno, where the server handles everything. (Assume this is a text-only game for simplicity). For example, to get information printed out to the user in the client, the server might send `PRINT string`, or `CHOOSE data` (to pick a card to play), etc. In this regard, the client is "dumb" and the server handles the game logic.

A quick example of how this might work on a protocol level:
Server sends: `PRINT Choose a card`
Server sends: `CHOOSE Red 1,Blue 1`  (user shown a button or something, and picks Red 1)
Client sends: `Red 1`

Let's say I have this architecture:
*Player Class*: stores the cards the user has, maybe some methods (such as `tellData(String data`) which would send PRINT data, `sendPM()` which could private message a user)

*Server Class*: handles authentication, allows users to create new games, shows users a list of games they can join

*Game Class*: handles users playing a card, handles switching to a new player for his or her turn, calls methods on player class like `tellData()`, `pickCard()`, etc

*How would I scale this, to run the server on multiple computers?* Right now, all of the users connect to one server, and require the Player, Server, and Game class to interact with each other. If someone could provide some suggestions, and/or point me to some good resources/books on this, it would be greatly appreciated (no, this is not a homework assignment or something for a business, this is just a personal project and curiosity of mine). In terms of scalability, I'd like to just be able to add another server, and handle the additional load of players--but the most concurrent connections would be 1000.

Also, would this become significantly more difficult of a scalability challenge if we added in more games?

Furthermore, what is the best way to store game data? In a SQL database, or serializing objects, or what? By this, I mean let's say 3 users are in a game of Uno, and want to return to it later. I don't want to store their cards and information about the game in the Player/Server/Game class (RAM) forever - I want to dump this somewhere, so when the user logs in, the info can be loaded from however this was dumped into RAM, and then the appropriate Player/Game objects.

*Finally, how can I make changes to the server without having to kill it, and restart it?* Assume the server was written in Java or Python.

If anyone can provide suggestions or some resources it would be greatly appreciated - this includes changing the architecture I originally stated.

Thanks for any and all help!!

**EDIT: Are there any good books or talks you all would recommend on the subject?**

Answer (score 0):

**1.Scalability:**
Involves an application architecture there across multiple server instances the session is replicated/shared and load balanced. You can choose to implement a message queue (**rabbitmq**) / ESB(enterprise service bus) architecture for your app.

**2.Ease of scaling:**
Depends on deployment and the servers you choose.

**3.Pesistance:**
Game for a person involves his particular game state at any point of time. If you could represent state information semantically you can have the data in markup savefiles, or store the state information directly into a DB.
Else, you may need to serialize objects and store them on filesystem / as a BLOB in DB in case the state space is humongous.

**4.Hot deployment:**
JVM mostly always will need a restart to reload class files, hence on java server side you will always need to restart. In Ruby/Rails is certain parts of the application can be hot deployed. If your need 100% hot deployability, perhaps Erlang is the answer.

*To improve concurrency you can also use evented server/app architectures: thin/eventmachine  for ruby or apache mina, jboss netty for java.*